# Valid assumptions for Poisson as limit of Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, statistics, poisson-distribution

Two different sources use two different sets of assumptions for the Poisson distribution as a limiting case of the binomial distribution. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxtRkcSzvaISXwUvtNuG54et3UQqJ7r5At) sets
$$n\rightarrow\infty, p\rightarrow0, np\rightarrow\lambda$$

And [this](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/LEISTATS/poisson.pdf) sets
$$n\rightarrow\infty, np=\lambda$$

The derivation remains the same. Is there any difference between the implications of these assumptions, and if so, what is it?
If there is no difference, can we derive one from the other?

Comment: it's the same..

Comment: Can you show/prove that it is the same?

Comment: They both end up with the same result, so they are the same (at least in that sense). For your first assumption, it is easy (I hope) to believe that there is no loss in generality of taking $np \equiv \lambda$. (It is implicit here that $p \equiv p(n)$, i.e., the dependency of $p$ on $n$ is suppressed.)

Comment: I don't understand the notation. What do you mean by $np\equiv\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.  Assuming $\lambda > 0$, the condition $np = \lambda$ implies that as $n \to \infty$, we must have $p \to 0^+$.

Conversely, we only require $np \to \lambda$ asymptotically, rather than identically, as long as both $n \to \infty$ and $p \to 0^+$.  (Some sources omit the $+$ because it is understood that $0 < p < 1$.)  In fact, this (first) characterization is slightly more general than the second, but in practice, nothing is lost by assuming $np = \lambda$.

Comment: Is there any place where the difference in assumptions matters?

Answer (score 0):

There is the estimate of the total variation norm
$$\|Bin(n, p) - Pois(np)\| \leq n\|Ber(p) - Pois(p)\| \leq np^2.$$
This holds for every $n \in \mathbb{N}, p \in [0, 1]$. See section 3.6 of [https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).
Now if you consider a sequence $p_n$ with $np_n \to \lambda$, then a natural condition for the above norm to go to $0$ is that $p_n \to 0$. But the inequalities behind the estimate let's you formulate a more general condition under which sums of Bernoullis converge to a Poisson.

Comment: What is the takeaway? Are the two assumptions different? And what is the general condition for when sums of Bernoullis converge to a Poisson?

Comment: The takeaway is the general estimates explained in the book, which gives the rate of convergence. For example, the maximum discrepancy of a probability between Binomial(n, p) and Pois(np) is $n p^2$. In applications it means that if we observe binomials $k$ out of $n$ where $\hat{p} = k/n$ is small, then we should consider modeling the $k$s as Poissons with mean $\lambda n$ and then estimate $\lambda$, which is an instantaneous rate.

Comment: That's ok. You have discussed the rate of convergence of a binomial to a Poisson. How does your answer address my questions on how/whether the two assumptions are different>